# How could you predict customer churn using transactions date?

Tags: machine-learning

I new in machine learning, I would like to predict churn using dates of transactions. I tried to prepare my data and I couldn't obtain good results.

[image]

Could someone suggest something? I would like to predict, for example;

```
cust ID ; A, B , C, D  churn ; 0, 1 ,1 0.
```

I don't know how to use dates (weeks) to prepare my dataset. Thank you for your time and regards!

Comment: Perhaps more suitable for the Data Science community (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use week as categorical features and then do one-hot encoding for it.

Comment: Will you have a simple example of what it would look like? It would be to predict, if each customer left (1) or stayed (0). Taking into consideration; Cust ID; A, B, C, D churn; 0, 1, 1 0. Thank you!